# Finding a match and replacing with a sequence of numbers

Tags: awk, sed, edit

I have files that look like:

```
file1.txt
i0  AAAAAA
    AAAAAA
i0  AAAAAA
    AAAAAA
i0  AAAAAA
    AAAAAA
```

I would like to replace all of the `i0` with a sequence of numbers so the resulting file looks like:

```
  file1.txt
    i0  AAAAAA
        AAAAAA
    i1  AAAAAA
        AAAAAA
    i2  AAAAAA
        AAAAAA
```

What I have now is:

```
awk -vRS=i0 '{$0=n$0;ORS=RT}++n'
```

But this results in:

```
file1.txt
i10  AAAAAA
     AAAAAA
i20  AAAAAA
     AAAAAA
i30  AAAAAA
     AAAAAA
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Why not just `awk '/^i0/{ sub(/^i0/, "i"n++) }1'`

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you!

Comment: or `awk -F '[ ]' '$1=="i0" {$1="i" c++}1' file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work

```
awk -vRS=i0 '{$0=n$0;ORS=RT}++n'
```

Because RT is set each time a record is read. It contains the input text that matched the text denoted by RS, the record separator.

Just replace `RT` with hardcoded `"i"`

```
awk -v RS=i0 '{$0=n$0;ORS="i"}++n'
```

The output will be:

```
i1 AAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAA
i2 AAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAA
i3 AAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAA
```